# javascript listening multiple socket channels with echo

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, vue.js, laravel-echo

I try to code a chat application. I use (on the server side): `php` `laravel 5.4` and `pusher` and (on the client side) `vue.js` and `laravel-echo`.

I've already made one chat group, what is a "public chat room". Now I'm working on private chat rooms.

**My question:** what is the best practice (on the client side) to listen all the channels of rooms whats the user belongs to.

**My goal:** to check that (like on facebook messenger web page) every channel of private and public rooms.

Now I have this in `chat-window` component:

```
created() {
  axios.get('/chatroom').then(response => {
      this.chatRooms = response.data;
      console.log('get /chatroom response: ' + response.data);
  });

  axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
      this.messages = response.data;
      console.log('get /messages response: ' + response.data);
  });

  Echo.join('chatroom')
      .here((users) => {
          this.usersInRoom = users;
      })
      .joining((user) => {
          this.usersInRoom.push(user);
      })
      .leaving((user) => {
          this.usersInRoom = this.usersInRoom.filter(u => u != user)
      })
      .listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
          this.messages.push({
              message: e.message.message,
              user: e.user
          });
      });
  }
});
```

But this listens only the `chatroom` channel. How can the client listen all the chatrooms (`this.chatRooms`) ?

Thanks the answers in advance!

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Thx the question, Yes I did, I m going to write the solution

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out that **every user has to be its own** channel.

Then I modified my `chat-window` component:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 60px">
        <chat-room-picker :chatrooms="chatRooms" :newmessage="newmessage" :defaultchatroomid="pickedchatroomid" class="pull-left" v-on:chatroompicked="chatroompick"></chat-room-picker>
        <chat-room-creator class="pull-right"></chat-room-creator>
      </div>
        <chat-room :chatroomid="pickedchatroomid" :newmessage="newmessage"></chat-room>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
     userId: loggedUserFS.id,
     userName: loggedUserFS.name,
     chatRooms: chatRoomsFS,
     pickedchatroomid: defaultChatRoomIdFS,
     newmessage: {},
    }
 },
 methods: {
   chatroompick(id) {
     this.pickedchatroomid = id;
   },
 },
 created() {
  // this.getCookiesParams();
  var tmp = this.chatRooms[0];
  this.pickedchatroomid = tmp.id;
   var channelName = 'chat-' + this.userId;
   console.debug(channelName + ", channel init.");
   window.Echo.join(channelName)
       .listen('NewMessageEvent', (e) => {
           console.debug("incoming message on " + channelName + ": " + JSON.stringify(e));
           console.debug(e.message.chatRoom_id + "==" + this.pickedchatroomid);
           console.debug(channelName +" : "+ e.message.chatRoom_id + "==" + this.pickedchatroomid);
           // TODO: finish it
           if(e.message.chatRoom_id == this.pickedchatroomid) { // if the reciced message comes from the pickedchatroom
             console.debug("reciced message comes from the pickedchatroom!");
             this.newmessage = e;
           } else { // if the reciced message does not come from the pickedchatroom
             this.newmessage = e;
           }
       });
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

I made a `chat-room-picker` what is a drop down and you can change the chatrooms with it. And there is a `chat-room` component, for showing the messages of current chat-room. There are `vue-watch`-es in both component and the new message is changed, the chat-room is add the message (if the message is belongs to the current chat-room) else dont do anything, and the `chat-room-picker` starts blinking if the message belongs to other room.

`chat-room-picker` watch:

```
  watch : {
    newmessage : function (value) {
      var message = value;
      var picker = $(".chatRoomPicker");
      //TODO: check that the message belongs to current chat room
      picker.addClass("blink");
      picker.on("click", function() {
        picker.removeClass("blink");
      });
    }
  }
```

chat-room component's watch part:

```
  watch : {
    chatroomid : function (value) { // if chat-room is changed
      this.getChatRoomMessages();
    },
    newmessage : function(value) {  // TODO: here or parent component check the room of the message
      console.debug("newmessage received:" + JSON.stringify(value));
      var msgTmp = value.message;
      msgTmp.user = value.user;

      this.messages.push(msgTmp);
    }
  },
```

server side (in controller):

```
broadcast(new NewMessageEvent($message, $user, $usersOfChatRoom));
```

and my `broadcastOn` method of the `NewMessageEvent` looks like this:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    $channels = [];
    foreach ($this->usersOfChatRoom as $addressee) {
      if($addressee->id != $this->user->id) {
        array_push($channels, new PresenceChannel('chat-' . $addressee->id));
      }
    }
    Log::debug("broadcastOn channels: " . json_encode($channels));
    return $channels;
  //
}
```

I know its not finished, but I commented where should finish the code.

It maybe not the most elegant way, but it works. If anyone else has other solution pls share it!

Comment: so whenever you broadcast the event of a, lets say chatroom in which there are N users. you broadcast the event N times? each time to each users private channel? *edit* well actually n-1 because of the user that sent the message

Comment: Hello! I updated my answer. Yes I do. So when one client make a msg, it is sent to the server, where the server broadcasts it to the others of the chatroom

Comment: Thanks. Was having trouble with this because I was thinking that there should be a better way but apparently broadcasting N-1 times a message is the way. Good luck in the future!

Comment: I recommend you that check how facebook's messenger page works: www.messenger.com. You have an id, and Im sure that you have your own channel where your client is listening. It gave me the idea. :) I wish the same!

Comment: @LakiGeri I have done the same. and everything works, but I am experiencing [1 - 1.5] seconds delay for receiving the chats. How about your case?
I tried to send a message to 200 user channels.

Please take a look at my implementations for group chat using pusher & socket .io

https://github.com/rameezrami/laravel-socket-io-group-chat
https://github.com/rameezrami/laravel-pusher-group-chat

Comment: @RameezRami, to be honest, it was my first chat-socket connection application. Nowadays I dont work with php, so I can not help you. Sorry!

Comment: @LakiGeri sorted it out,  the delay was in the bridge of Redis - SocketServer. works everything as expected now